# Getters in ES6 functional component React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, getter-setter, getter

I am using stateless component in React and I found issue with using Getters.

for the statefull component (class based component) it is properly working but how can I use this in stateless(functional component);

````
 // this is code for statefull component(class based component)

get lookupsOfSelectedGroup(){
        const lookUps = this.props.mainLookups.filter(
          item => item.extras.parent === this.state.activeGroup
        );

        if (lookUps[0] && lookUps[0].responseStatus === 200) {
          return lookUps[0].response.lookup;
        }

        return [];
  }


// this is the code for functional component I did:

    get lookupsOfSelectedGroup =()=> {
        const lookUps = this.props.mainLookups.filter(
          item => item.extras.parent === this.state.activeGroup
        );

        if (lookUps[0] && lookUps[0].responseStatus === 200) {
          return lookUps[0].response.lookup;
        }

        return [];
      }    ```

Cannot find name 'get'.
````

Comment: Have you tried `get lookupsOfSelectedGroup(){ ... }`

Comment: Stateless component does not have an instance, how do you expect to call this getters? Also your `get lookupsOfSelectedGroup = arrow function` wont work even for class based components.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use the `get` and `set` keywords in ES6 classes and object literals.

[Check the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

A getter can only be defined as a property of an object or a class. You cannot define them directly in the body of a function.

You will either need to replace `lookupsOfSelectedGroup` with a plain function (probably the better solution), or wrap it in an object literal.